# Datagrip deletes Comments before statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datagrip

When I create a sql statement i usually add a comment header on the top like this

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      *******
-- Create Date: *******
-- Description: *******
-- =============================================

ALTER VIEW ***.***
AS 
   --something
```

But whenever i run it Datagrip cuts out the Comment at the top. Is there a setting that i could disable to keep it from doing this?

I looked through all the settings that alter how comments behave aswell as the sql formatter.

Comment: Perhaps try with `/* comment */` block - tbh these are preferable too.

Comment: I believe it can be changed under 'File | Settings | Editor | Copyright | Formatting | SQL'.

Comment: Is it SQL Server?

Comment: I can also reproduce when trying to add comments before DDL statements (SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

set For selection execute to Exactly as one statement and select a whole query before execution. Then your comments will be in db.
[Comments-lost-when-saving-View-in-MS-SQL-Server](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-6546/Comments-lost-when-saving-View-in-MS-SQL-Server)